# Error Importing .csv file into pgsql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am attempting to upload data into my postgres database using an excel file that I have converted into a .csv file.  My .csv file is a simple test file, it contains only one row of data, all of which have cells that are formatted to be text and the titles of which match the columns in my data model.

The data model I am attempting to upload data to looks like:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    journalists = models.ManyToManyField(Journalist, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name="publications")
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    media_kit_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

When I go into psql and enter the command:

```
\copy apricot_app_publication from '~/Desktop/sampleDBPubs.csv';
```

I get back the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "title,url,email,media_kit_url,notes,tags,image_url,journalists" 

CONTEXT:  COPY apricot_app_publication, line 1, column id: "title,url,email,media_kit_url,notes,tags,image_url,journalists"
```

I looked at this question [Importing csv file into pgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806047/importing-csv-file-into-pgsql) which addresses the same issue, but the answer given was that the error means that "you're trying to input something into an integer field which is not an integer...", but my data model does not have any integer fields, so I do not know how to solve the issue.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the issue?

Comment: `journalists = models.ManyToManyField(Journalist, blank=True)` reeks of an integer field referencing a Journalist's id from a separate table...

Comment: is there any way to work around that? I just tried adding a random integer to the journalist and tag columns just to see what would happen and i get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered my own question.  There is an automatically generated id column that is created behind the scenes on anything that has a many to many relationship in my Django app.  Thus, the database is expecting an integer to be added from the .csv file, which is the id, but my .csv file does not have an id column and I do not want to add one as want the id's to continue to be auto-generated.

To get around this, I just have to specify which columns my file is going to provide data for in parenthesis after the table name:

EX:

```
\copy apricot_app_tag(title) FROM '~/Desktop/Sample_Database_Files/tags.csv' with csv header
```

Where 'title' is the only column in the tag table I want to update.